# What does it mean for a caliber to be flat shooting?

Tags: hunting, terminology, guns

Certain calibers such as the 300 Winchester Magnum are often called flat shooting.

What does that mean and why would a hunter care that the caliber is flat shooting when selecting a rifle to go hunting with?

Comment: Related https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/21713/when-hunting-what-is-point-blank-range?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bullets follow a [parabolic arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_ballistics) as seen below,

[image]

[Image Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:M855_drop_during_25-meter_zeroing_trajectory_M16A2_M4.jpg#file)

As you can see the yellow line is a bullet fired from a longer barrel which results in a higher velocity and thus less drop over distance. In this case the yellow line is a flatter shooting rifle.

Cartridges that are regarded as flatter shooting have one or both of two things going for them, they are traveling at a much higher velocity to start with and or have a better ballistic coefficient resulting in less drag.

See for example 6.5 Creedmore vs. 308 Winchester.

[image]
<sub>(source: [gunwerks.com](https://www.gunwerks.com/uploads/images/original/BDC.jpg))</sub>

[Source](https://lifeundersky.com/6-5-creedmoor-vs-308-winchester/)

The reason that this matters is that with a flatter shooting cartridge you don't have to get the range to the animal as accurately because the bullet is dropping less. This leads to the concept of [point-blank-range](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/21713/what-is-a-cartridge-s-point-blank-range/21714#21714) as fully explained [here](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/21713/what-is-a-cartridge-s-point-blank-range/21714#21714)

Comment: ..is it common in american ballistic charts to use meters AND inches in one graph?

Comment: @FlyingThunder what concerns me more is the first chart doesn’t start at zero, the bullet leaves the barrel at -2.5 inches.

Comment: @Notts90 No it's that the barrel is 2.5 inches below the sights.

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh ah zero is set the the sights, makes sense.

Comment: @FlyingThunder I am assuming that Wikipedia got that chart from the US military and that probably explains the meters and inches. Normally no, its inches and yards